# Problem with hyperlinks from an InDesign generated PDF - only works if browser is open

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

I'm at a new job so I'm not sure if this is a Firefox issue or hyperlink issue. Haven't experienced it before.

I created a few hyperlinks (three spots for our company website, two for company email) as part of a catalog created in InDesign. Did PDF export and ticked to include hyperlinks.

If Mozilla Firefox is running then all of the links work. Website opens in new tabs, email opens in Thunderbird (what we're using here). However, if I close Firefox then it freezes up and crashes Acrobat.

Anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried modifying the links in Acrobat to see what would happen?

Comment: Have you tried having a different browser open and seeing if the links open there?

Comment: Is Acrobat updated? What version are you running? I remember a problem like this back a few updates ago.

Comment: Brand new Acrobat off Creative Cloud installed two days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things come to mind. Acrobat has a number of hooks into the OS, and even after a fresh install (and especially after an update) it's almost always necessary to restart the system before everything works normally. OS X and Windows are both subject to this. The other is that Foxit may also have its own hooks into the OS that argue with Acrobat, although I've never used it so that's really just speculation on my part.

Comment: Don't like the idea of marking myself the answer so gave it to you.

Answer (score 0):

They also use Foxit PDF - actually my computer is now the only one with Acrobat. I opened it in Foxit and got an error message on the links about Trusted Privileges. Looked up what that meant and changed the preference in Foxit.

It then worked in Foxit.

Opened it up and start playing with the comparable setting in Adobe Acrobat only to find that the links now work - without actually making any changes. No idea why changing the setting in Foxit made a difference in Acrobat unless I missed something else that I did.